# Auto Select Locale for Android Text To Speech

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I've developed an app that is published in multiple languages. The app also uses some of the TextToSpeech capabilities of Android.

I want to know if its possible to detect the language of the phone and automatically set my locale instead of asking the user to decide the locale?

```
 int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
```

I want this to be set automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault())
```

to set the default locale.  I don't know how that will react if the default doesn't have voice dictionaries on the device though.

Edit:  Or maybe I do.  It would return  LANG_MISSING_DATA or LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED. In those cases you should probably set a backup locale.

Comment: There are people that use *more then one language* every day, even in one sentence. E.g. russian language with english proper nouns, so TTS will speak with horrible accent (со ТТС вилл спик виз хоррабл акцент). Sometimes it's necessary to allow user choose TTS language (in book reader applications like fbreader).

Comment: True, but that's not what he asked for. He asked for it to automatically use the phone's locale